# c++ Lambda function, accesses Var1 by reference. the result is strange

Tags: c++, lambda, reference

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()

{
    int v1 = 1, v2 = 4; 

    auto sum_return_lambda = [](int var1) -> auto { return [&var1](int var2 ) { return var1 + var2; }; };
    // sum_return_lambda returns auto type, which is a lambda function: [var1](var2){ return var1 + var2;}. 
    // This returned lambda function takes one parameter: var2
    auto dbl = [](const auto& func,  int var2) { return func(var2) * 2;};

    auto returned_lambda = sum_return_lambda(v1);
    cout << "returned_lambda(v2)= " << returned_lambda(v2) << endl;
    cout << "dbl(returned_lambda, v2)= " << dbl(returned_lambda, v2) << endl; 

    
    cout << "v1: "<< v1 << ", v2: " << v2 << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

v1 = 1, v2 =4, v1 is passed in by reference. I expect
returned_lambda(v2)= 5, and dbl(returned_lambda, v2)= 10.

But this is what I got:
returned_lambda(v2)= 8
dbl(returned_lambda, v2)= 65542

At the end of program, I check the value of v1 and v2, they are not changed:
v1: 1, v2: 4

Where does 65542 come from? why returned_lambda(v2)= 8, not 5??

Thank you!

Comment: you shot yourself into your foot here: `[&var1]`.

Comment: `var1` is local to the lambda, the lambda you return stores a dangling reference

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
auto sum_return_lambda = [](int var1) -> auto { return [&var1](int var2 ) { return var1 + var2; }; };
                             // ^^^
```

Here `var1` is local to the outer lambda expression and the lambda returned from it holds a dangling reference. If you want to capture the variable passed to `sum_reference_lambda` you have to pass it via reference:

```
auto sum_return_lambda = [](int& var1) -> auto { return [&var1](int var2 ) { return var1 + var2; }; };
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ae8MYsjYq)

> Where does 65542 come from? why returned_lambda(v2)= 8, not 5??

The output of your code could be anything, because it has undefined behavior.